# On error exit sub and return error to sub that called erroneous sub

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, error-logging

**Some background:**

*Precursor:* I have looked around SO at the other Error Handling questions, but I haven't been able to fully apply the answers to my situation. I feel like `Err.Raise` is how I would accomplish what I'll describe below. But, I'm not sure how to implement it in the way I need. If I were to use `Err.Raise` how would I exit the Sub1-15 first before raising the error code in the main sub?

That being said,

I have a large Excel VBA project that performs a plethora of different routines. I chose to call all routines from one main routine for means of later maintenance on the individual routines. I have an `On Error` handler in my main sub that I would like to have triggered if an error is thrown in any of the routines called from that main routine.

**Is there a way to:**

1. Record the

   - Error type that occurred
   - Error message
   - **Sub that raises the error**
2. On Error exit that sub to return to the main sub, then

   - Raise the error that just occurred in the other sub so that the *NotifyandRepair* Error Handler is called?

I have the following situation

```
Sub MainSub()
    On Error GoTo NotifyandCorrect
    Call Sub1
    Call Sub2
    ...
    Call Sub15
    Exit Sub
NotifyandCorrect:
    'Send copy of faulty file, the error code and Sub that caused it
    'Then stop macro execution completely
End Sub

Sub Sub1()
    On Error Exit Sub1 and raise current Error in MainSub(?)
    'Perform data checks
End Sub

Sub Sub2()
    On Error Exit Sub2 and raise current Error in MainSub(?
    'Modify data groups
End Sub

Sub Sub15()
    On Error Exit Sub15 and raise current Error in MainSub(?
    'Clean up work
End Sub
```

Is there anyway I can avoid having to do something like below for each of Sub1-Sub15?

```
Sub MainSub()
        On Error GoTo NotifyandCorrect
        Call Sub1
        Call Sub2
        ...
        Call Sub15
        Exit Sub
    NotifyandCorrect:
        'Send copy of faulty file, the error code and Sub that caused it
        'Then stop macro execution completely
    End Sub
    ...
    ...
Sub Sub15()
    On Error Goto HaltExecution
    'Clean up work
    Exit Sub
HaltExecution:
    'Note Error message & type
    'Note that Sub15 is where error occurred
    End Sub
```

**Closing Questions**

1. Is this at all possible?
2. If this isn't possible, how should I handle this to do something like what I described? What would you suggest (please provide an example if you can)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle errors in your "child" methods, and have them "re-throw" the error (using `Err.Raise` in the error handler subroutine) so the caller gets to see it - when re-throwing, specify the method's name as the "source". The following code produces this output:

> ```
> 5            Invalid procedure call or argument        DoSomething1
> 9            Subscript out of range      DoSomething2
> ```

```
Public Sub MainSub()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    DoSomething1
    DoSomething2

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething1()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Err.Raise 5

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "DoSomething1", Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething2()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Err.Raise 9

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "DoSomething2", Err.Description
End Sub
```

> *Is there anyway I can avoid having to do something like below for each of Sub1-Sub15?*

No. Each procedure must handle runtime errors, there's no way around it.

---

Specifying method names in hard-coded strings is annoying. By encapsulating each procedure into its own object (say, some `ICommand` implementation), you can achieve the same result by leveraging the `TypeName` function:

**Module1**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MainSub()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    RunCommand New DoSomething1
    RunCommand New DoSomething2

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub RunCommand(ByVal command As ICommand)
    command.Execute
End Sub
```

**ICommand** (class module)

```
Public Sub Execute()
End Sub
```

**DoSomething1** (class module)

```
Option Explicit
Implements ICommand

Private Sub ICommand_Execute()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Err.Raise 5

ErrHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, TypeName(Me), Err.Description
End Sub
```

**DoSomething2** (class module)

```
Option Explicit
Implements ICommand

Private Sub ICommand_Execute()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Err.Raise 9

ErrHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, TypeName(Me), Err.Description
End Sub
```

The `ICommand` interface isn't really needed, but formalizes the way each `DoSomething` command is to be called. The idea is to have an *object* to implement each procedure - that way you can have `TypeName(Me)` as your error source, and never need to hard-code a string. You'll have 15 methods in 15 dedicated class modules, instead of 15 procedures in a single standard module.

Comment: So the `Err.Raise` not only recalls the error, but also causes the code to move back to the original sub/main routine to trigger `NotifyandRepair`?

Comment: Yes. Any error occurring inside an error-handling subroutine needs to be handled by the caller. Note that calling `Err.Raise` *without any arguments* would effectively "re-throw" the exact error that occurred, for the caller to handle - you only need to specify arguments because you want to specify the `Source` here.

Comment: I had no idea that `Err.Raise` was capable of passing arguments as you described. That's perfect for my situation, thank you! It's unfortunate to have to place the error handling in each sub, but alas I suppose it's a small price to pay, right?

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder I added a more OOP approach that doesn't rely on magic strings, if it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Mat'sMug, I really appreciate how much effort you put into explaining this to me. For this specific project in going to stick with the first option you explained since I planned on keeping each part (large macro) of my Add-In in separate Modules. But, I will keep the second method in mind for future projects because I didn't really understand the use of class modules until your explanation. I learn something new every time I talk to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Err.Number` and `Err.Description` to get info about the error.

Next, I would suggest creating a temp `string` and updating it whenever a new sub is entered. such as:

```
Sub Sub1()
temp= "sub1"
...
End Sub

Sub Sub2()
temp= "sub2"
...
End Sub
```

So whenever an error is handled, the string temp holds the value of the sub it occurred in.

Comment: But, how would I return to my MainSub and raise the NotifyandRepair Error Handler when the error occurs?

Comment: I think you just need to remove  'Exit Sub' on the main sub, and then whenever an error occurs on sub1 or sub2 you immediately go back to NotifyandCorrect in the main sub.